# $\ell_p$-norm of a vector versus norm of coordinate-wise sine of the vector

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, trigonometry, normed-spaces

We know that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 1$. Can such an asymptotic equivalence hold also for vectors of sines?

For $\mathbb{R}^n$, equip i with the $\ell_p$-norm, where for $v=(v_i)_{i\in [n]}$,
$$\|v\|_p = \left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \lvert v_i\rvert^p \right)^{1/p}$$
Let $v = (\theta_1,\theta_2,\dots,\theta_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (with $\lvert \theta_i \rvert \leq \pi/2$ just to be safe).
Denote $\sin(v) = (\sin{\theta_1},\sin{\theta_2},\dots,\sin{\theta_n}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

> Is there any relation between $\|v\|_p$ and $\|\sin{v}\|_p$ as $\|v\|_p \to 0$? ``

Even if not an exact limit value, is there at least some asymptotic bounds, say $\|v\|_p = O_p\left( \|\sin{v}\|_p\right)$ as $\|v\|_p \to 0$?

*UPDATE: One direction of inequality is easy. Since $\lvert x \rvert \geq \lvert \sin{x} \rvert$ for small $x$, this immediately gives
$$\sum \limits_{i=1}^n \lvert \theta_i \rvert^p \geq \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \lvert \sin{\theta_i} \rvert^p$$
So for $v$ close to $0$ in norm, $\|v\|_p \geq \|\sin{v}\|_p$.
But is there some bound in the other direction for $v$ close to $0$ in norm?